# Laravel Forge: Repository Not Found

Tags: laravel, github, forge

Running into this error on forge and I'm not sure what to try next. Here's the situation and what I've tried thus far.

```
Cloning into '{site_name}'...
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists
```

This forge account is for the company I work for which has an associated organization on github of which I am have an owner role. Forge is not able to read from any of the repositories owned by this organization. The above error started occurring after the owner of the github account logged into forge was removed from the organization.

**What I've tried**

1. Unlinking/relinking github in forge under the `Source Control` tab.
2. Set organization, third-party application access policy to `no restrictions`
3. Tried having other team members in the organization sign into github on forge
4. Adding the ssh key forge supplies for any given site to the deploy key section for that site's associated repository. This always yields the same error, `key already in use`.
5. Double, triple, quadruple checked the spelling of the repository name/path

I've tried reaching out to the forge tech support, but none of their suggestions have worked so far.

Another note, I am able to have forge connect to any of my personal repositories but none of the ones I have created for under the organization.

Has anyone else had issues related to github organizations on forge?

Comment: Is your URL `git@github.com:<org>/<repo>`?

Comment: Vonc - yes that's the URL structure.

Comment: Can you set `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` to `ssh -v`, and try again your clone? That would give more information.

Comment: https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/managing-deploy-keys/ Check Machine Users.

Comment: @Panda4Man did you find a solution for this? I know it's an old question but Im facing the exact same problem, after removing a developer from our organisation that was connected with forge

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue. When we removed one of our ex-developers account from the organization, forge couldn't access any of our repo.  The issue we was because of the ssh key. The forge ssh key of the repo was added to that ex-developer's account, removed it from his account and added to to an existing devs, who is on the organization account and it worked.

*You can get the ssh key from the meta tab on the forge servers page